# ls command doesn't show any files in home directory

Tags: users, home-directory, windows-subsystem-for-linux, ls

[image: ls output]

```
tommy@LAPTOP-6AUB639F:~$ pwd
/home/tommy
tommy@LAPTOP-6AUB639F:~$ ls
tommy@LAPTOP-6AUB639F:~$
```

Answer (score 3):

The [previous answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1339725/301745) is perfectly correct, but depending on your expectation it may not really answer your question.  I'm thinking that you might be expecting that listing the contents of your home directory in WSL will list the contents of your Windows profile (or perhaps Documents) folder.  That would explain your surprise that `ls` wasn't showing any files.

I'm going to use some "beginner" terminology below just because I don't know your experience level with Linux.

Under WSL, your home directory is, as you see `/home/tommy`.  That's a subdirectory `tommy` of a subdirectory `home` of the root directory `/`.  That root directory in WSL exists in a virtual drive (known as a filesystem); it is *not* the same as your `C:\` drive.  So, `/home/tommy` in WSL/Linux is not the same location as `C:\Users\tommy` in Windows.

In fact, by default, the `C:\` drive is "mounted" into `/mnt/c` under WSL.  So assuming your Windows user name is also "tommy", then you can likely find your Windows "home" directory (a.k.a. the user profile directory) at `/mnt/c/Users/tommy`, along with its subdirectory `/mnt/c/Users/Documents`.  Doing an `ls` in the former, at least, is guaranteed to return quite a few results.

Answer (score 1):

If the `ls` command does not provide any output, then no visible files are present in the folder.

To view any folder, use the `-a` (or `--all`) switch. It will show at least the current folder as `.` and the parent folder as `..`. If there are hidden files or folders present, i.e., of which the name starts with `.`, they will appear as well.

You can create an empty file with the `touch` command:

```
touch newfile
```

If you now execute `ls`, does it show up?